# PHP only show values in Array greater than 0

Tags: php

I have an array of select drop downs:

```
<select name="ultimate[<?php echo $theme['id']; ?>]">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<select name="ultimate[<?php echo $theme['id']; ?>]">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
......
......
......
```

When I print these results with:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

I get this returned:

```
[ultimate] => Array ( [1] => 3 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 3 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 2 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 0 [13] => 0 [14] => 0 [15] => 0 [16] => 0 [17] => 0 [18] => 0 [19] => 0 [20] => 0 [21] => 0 [22] => 0 [23] => 0 [24] => 0 [25] => 0 [26] => 0 [27] => 0 [28] => 0 [29] => 0 [30] => 0 [31] => 0 [32] => 0 [33] => 0 [34] => 0 [35] => 0 [36] => 0 [37] => 0 )
```

How would I go about only getting the values of each id that are greater than 0?

Comment: All you show us is a piece of HTML. What array are you talking about? Please clarify your question.

Comment: `if($_POST['ultimate'][$currentId] > 0) { … }` is an option, but as @Felix Kling stated, your input is bit meager.

Comment: Ah now it makes more sense. One straightforward option is to just iterate over the array.

Comment: `empty(0)` will return `true` also...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will probably do what do you want

```
foreach ($ultimate as $key => $var)
{
    if ($var > 0) echo $key.":".$var;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$ultimate = array_filter($ultimate);`

Comment: Sooo badass solution! Love it.